# Apache POI cannot create XMLSlideShow object

Tags: java, apache-poi, xpages, lotus-notes

I am using an old version of Apache POI (3.8) on my Domino server. I want to create some presentation files so I started with a basic sample code:

```
package org.quintessens.poi;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlideLayout;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlideMaster;

public class Presentation {

    public void createXSLF() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("createXSLF()");
          //create an empty presentation
          XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
          System.out.println("Available slide layouts:");      
          //getting the list of all slide masters
          for(XSLFSlideMaster master : ppt.getSlideMasters()){     
             //getting the list of the layouts in each slide master
             for(XSLFSlideLayout layout : master.getSlideLayouts()){       
                //getting the list of available slides
                System.out.println(layout.getType());
             } 
          }
       }    
}
```

I have registered the class as a managed bean as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Prez</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>org.quintessens.poi.Presentation</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

I added a button on my XPage to call it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:button value="XSLF" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:Prez.createXSLF()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
    </xp:view>
```

When I run the code I get an error 500 message.

If I check my log I read:

> 2016-09-21 20:50:27   HTTP JVM: createXSLF() 2016-09-21 20:50:27
>   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information,
>   please consult error-log-0.xml located in C:/Program
>   Files/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs 2016-09-21 20:50:27   HTTP
>   JVM: CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for:
>   /apps/quintessens/ApachePO.nsf/test.xsp - HTTP Code: 500. For more
>   detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in
>   C:/Program Files/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

Sadly, the error log does not tell me much:

> 2016-09-21T20:50:26.872+02:00 ALLVARLIG CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown
>   2016-09-21T20:50:26.875+02:00 ALLVARLIG CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred
>   servicing request for: /apps/quintessens/ApachePO.nsf/test.xsp - HTTP
>   Code: 500

I tried to use the HSLF usermodel which goes well but which I do not want to use.

What should I do?

Comment: Upgrade to a release that isn't 5 years old? Make sure you [have all the required POI jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)?

Comment: A strategy that has served me well: Create another class with a void main method. Use that one to test out your bean. This way you can comfortably test it in Eclipse with the local debugger and see where it barfs. And yes: there's a good incentive to use the latest version that's supported on Java6

Comment: @Gagravarr Domino is still on java 6...

Comment: @stwissel I am developing not outside DDE

Comment: @PatrickKwinten DDE *is* an Eclipse environment, so you can run Java classes that have a void main method. 2 steps: a) You run that from the version controlled directory, not the NSF. You add the navigator view to be able to right click and "run as". No need to leave DDE

Comment: @stwissel the code has to run from a xpages app anyway so what use do I have running it from outside DDE?

Comment: I read: POI 3.11 and later requires the JDK version 1.6 or later.

POI 3.5 to 3.10 required the JDK version 1.5 or later. Versions prior to 3.5 required JDK 1.4+. https://poi.apache.org/howtobuild.html

Comment: Apache POI 3.15, released yesterday, still works just fine on Java 6, so you've no reason not to upgrade! POI may move to Java 7 in a release or two's time, but not yet

Comment: Patrick: Debugging - that's why you run in IN DDE as a standard Java app. Isolates your problem.